# How to build an afterSave query from its own object but including?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I need help building this Parse cloud code function, i guess its my query.get function because if I just send the push notification right from within the body of the afterSave function it works fine but i need information from the object that was saved and since the informations are inside of pointer cells from that object i need to query including its classes.

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Transaction", (request) => {

  const query = new Parse.Query('Transaction');
  query.include("atm.city")

  query.get(request.id)
    .then(function(post) {

    const message = post.object.get("atm.city.name")

    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
      method: "POST",
      url: "**********",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        "Authorization": "Basic **********"
      },
      body: {
      app_id: "**********", 
        included_segments: ["All"],
        contents: {en: `${message}`}
      }
    }).then(function (httpResponse) {}, function (httpResponse) {});
  })
});
```

---

EDIT:

When I wrote "It works fine" I meant that this code is called after saving a transaction but i'm not able to to finish the query successfully. I tried here and there to change something but the values are undefined or something like that.

Comment: I'm sorry but what exactly is your issue ?

Comment: @TanzimChowdhury I can't get the query to work. I want that after saving a transaction, i query the Transaction table but including a pointer atm.city so further I can send a push notification that includes this information.

Comment: Try printing an error message to the console and check out what the problem might be, it's difficult for us to debug without any specific error.